# How to append form data in Laravel 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 3 forms, 2 for files and 1 for additional information. I append the file path from the 2 forms to the additional info form like this:

```
init: function init() {
      this.on("success", function (file, message) {
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('patDetails'));
        formData.append('pdf_file', message);
        console.log(Array.from(formData.entries()));
      });
    }
```

And the other form:

```
init: function init() {
      this.on("success", function (file, message) {
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('patDetails'));
        formData.append('image_file', message);
        console.log(Array.from(formData.entries()));
      });
    }
```

The console shows 2 forms, but only shows this:

[image: Source code]

```
0: "_token"
1: "V5kwCKcEfx5AtvyuePbSbDLR4iZTGiEKbDIa8n21"

1: Array(2)
0: "title"
1: ""

2: Array(2)
0: "description"
1: ""

3: Array(2)
0: "tags"
1: ""

4: Array(2)
0: "price"
1: ""

5: Array(2)
0: "currency"
1: "euro"

6: Array(2)
0: "image_file"
1: "image_files/Bt4PA3WpBQTerpRTpydK9DBo0k325GPDRBy3LF0k.jpeg"
```

When I submit the form and `dd($request)`, it does not show the appended data, only the data from existing input fields.

How can I append the `message` from the 2 forms the details form?

Comment: you have formData in a local variable that goes away at the end of the init method, so its not doing anything. When you post your data to the server, you have to post your FormData object as the payload for it to actually do anything

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by replacing

```
 var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('patDetails'));
        formData.append('pdf_file', message);
```

with

```
 var formData = document.getElementById('patDetails');
          var input = document.createElement("input");
          input.type = "hidden";
          input.name = "pdf_file";
          input.value = message;
          formData.appendChild(input);
```